# How can I convert an unmanaged IntPtr type to a c# string?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I'm new to C# (from a native C++ background) and I'm trying to write a little UI to print windows broadcast messages among other things.  I've overridden the default WndProc message loop in my C# program like so:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Listen for operating system broadcasts.
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:

                this.richTextLog.Text += "WM_SETTINGCHANGE - lParam=" + m.LParam.ToString() + "\n";

                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

What I'd like to know, is how to obtain a string representation of the lParam object which is of type IntPtr.  It's essentially a void* in C++ land, can I cast it inside C# somehow?  Presumably doing so is inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`Marshal.PtrToStringAuto` Method (IntPtr)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewyktcaa.aspx)

> Allocates a managed `String` and copies all characters up to the first null character from a string stored in unmanaged memory into it.

Comment: Test for IntPtr.Zero first.  The info isn't exactly worth it.

Answer (score 8):

The above answer was great and it nearly solved the same issue for me but... I got what looks like Chinese characters back from the method (潆湵⁤瑡氠慥瑳漠敮爠灥慥整⁤浩条⁥慮敭›䌢⸢). What I had to do was use the Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr) method as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi.aspx 
and here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/555441/unitys-simplest-plugin-print-does-not-work.html.

Once I made the change, my String was in English once more. Not sure why that was happening, but there ya go!

Comment: [From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewyktcaa.aspx) "*If the current platform is Unicode, each ANSI character is widened to a Unicode character and this method calls PtrToStringUni. Otherwise, this method calls PtrToStringAnsi.*" Your system is a Unicode system but your unmanaged code was returning a Ansi string so the Auto system was choosing the wrong string encoding.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Thanks

Comment: I want to thank Ilia as well, but I cant Tag him for some reason.

Comment: I'm not getting readable chars using PtrToStringAnsi nor PtrToStringAuto :(

Comment: @Pedro77 Try to call it in the middle of your app (=not as the very first function). Give OGL a second to warm up. Create a viewport first.