# Convert/Cast String (from a textbox) to IntPtr C#

Tags: c#, casting, handle, intptr

I have a textbox where I want to input (manually) a Handle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zzrt.png)

My problem: to get the value from the textbox I need to do this:

```
textBoxHandle.Text;
```

but when I initialize my Handle as IntPtr (handle), this doesn't work:

```
IntPtr h = new IntPtr(textBoxHandle.Text);
```

I have tried doing

```
(IntPtr) textBoxHandle.Text
```

And also many other options I've read around here like Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi Method but they don't work/ they change the content.

My question: how do I get an IntPtr (handle) from the string (with a Handle format) that is in the textbox?

EDIT: In the textbox I would write 0x00040C66 for instance.

The final code should be:

```
IntPtr hWnd = new IntPtr(0x00040C66);
```

But changing the IntPtr for the value from the textbox.

EDIT: My question was marked as duplicated ([How can I convert an unmanaged IntPtr type to a c# string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175861/how-can-i-convert-an-unmanaged-intptr-type-to-a-c-sharp-string)) but it's not the same. It's not from IntPtr to String what I want. I need the opposite, from String to IntPtr.

Comment: So you want to create an IntPtr from a string of hex?

Comment: Try `new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(textBoxHandle.Text.Replace("0x", ""), 16))`

Comment: @Icemanind `Convert.ToInt32` handles the `0x` prefix without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I sorted it. My answer has been updated with the solution at the end. BTW, why is my question downvoted???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to parse the string into an `int` or `long` first, then construct the `IntPtr`.

```
IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(textBoxHandle.Text, 16));
// IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(textBoxHandle.Text, 16));
```

The second argument of `Convert.ToInt32` and `ToInt64` specifies the radix of the number and since you're parsing a hexadecimal number string, it needs to be 16.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted out my problem :) I didn't know a previous conversion to Int32 plus the radix was needed!

Comment: @самиJ.D. Glad to hear that! Be sure to also look into [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx), [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [difference between Int32.Parse and Convert.ToInt32](http://stackoverflow.com/a/199484/996081).