# C DLL does NOT Work in C# but Does work in C++

Tags: c#, c, dll, unsafe

I don`t understand this code below, that it is working with my c++ but it just does not want to work with c#.
Can you please help me to understand what is wrong here and i think i have to say that i am absolutely new to C#.

```
    My_Lib.h 
    extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl get(char** buffer);

    My_lib.c 
    void get(char** buffer)
    {
    *buffer = (char*)calloc(6, sizeof(char));
    assert(*buffer);

    buffer[5] = '\0';

    *buffer = "Hello";
    }
```

in my C#----->

```
public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("My_C_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

        unsafe public static extern void get(char** buffer);
    }
 //////////////////// Main()///////
        unsafe
            {
                char* my_buf;

                NativeMethods.get(&my_buf);

                string s = new string(my_buf);

                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

**NOTE:** Actually my DLL does Work when i call this c function from c++ but as i said above NOT in C#, there is no Errors but string s variable in C# prints some undefined sibols, but DLL "works"
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `char` in C# is not the same thing as `char` in C. Don't use raw pointers in C#, use [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke).

Comment: thank you, can you please show me how to use PInvoke in this case

Comment: Also note that you have a memory leak here.

Comment: Marshaling calls to unmanaged code that uses raw pointers and allocators, and uses string encodings that are not natively supported in C#, is **really hard to get right**. It is not a task for beginners.  Hire an expert, or start with an easier problem. This is not a site for tutoring people on complex subjects; do some reading up on interop and marshaling.

Comment: the bible on pinvoke is adam nathans book https://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X

Answer (score 1):

The code is nearly correct, but...

> C DLL does NOT Work in C# but Does work in C++

In C and C++ `char` is a 8-bit data type. In C# `char` is a 16-bit data type.

This means that C# expects that the pointer returned by the `get()` function is expected to be a "wide string", while in C++ expects an "ANSI string".

I simply changed one single line in your program:

```
*buffer = "H\0e\0l\0l\0o\0\0\0";
```

... and it works!

You may of course also use the "wide string" functions of the modern C compilers:

```
void get(wchar_t** buffer)
{
    *buffer = L"Hello";
}
```

**By the way**

There is another error in your program:

```
*buffer = (char*)calloc(6, sizeof(char));
...
*buffer = "Hello";
```

This makes no sense:

The second line (`*buffer = "Hello";`) will **not** copy the string to the memory allocated by `calloc`, but it will write the address of the string `"Hello"` to the variable `buffer` and the value (address) returned by `calloc` is overwritten (and lost).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to change the PInvoke signature of your C function to taking a `ref IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("My_C_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void get(ref IntPtr buffer);
```

To call this, you'll need to instantiate an IntPtr and pass it by reference to the C function (this is analagous to declaring a `char *` in C and passing it by address):

```
IntPtr ptr;
get(ref ptr);
// ptr is now an unmanaged pointer to the allocated string
```

Now, you need to [convert the pointed-to string to a managed `string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175861/how-can-i-convert-an-unmanaged-intptr-type-to-a-c-sharp-string). To do this you must make a copy of the string.

```
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

- Be sure you understand the distinctions between ANSI and Unicode strings and make sure you call the appropriate `PtrToString...()` variant.
- Note that **the .NET runtime will not manage the allocated `ptr` for you** since it was allocated by unmanaged code. You must free it yourself using whatever the appropriate mechanism is for your DLL (ideally, the DLL should provide a corresponding free function since it is the one who allocated the memory in the first place).
- For robustness, add appropriate error / null pointer checking. Make sure `get()` succeeded and that `ptr` is not `IntPtr.Zero`.
- To avoid leaks, if there is any possibility of any code throwing an exception between the time `get()` returns and the time you free the pointer, the [`try/finally` construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) is your friend.

(Aside: Note that `get` is a [Contextual Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) in C# and thus while you can use it as an identifier, you may prefer not to in order to avoid confusion.)